# change form action from aspx page to master page behind it

Tags: forms, checkbox, asp.net

i have a master page and a child aspx page, coneected to each other. the master page has the form in it. Now the child page has checkboxes, whose value i would like to pass to another child page with same master page behind it. 
Can i change the action=abc.aspx and method=post?
How can i send all the checkbox values (checkbox.text = abc@oke.com) to the next page?
there are lots of these values that need to pass to nex tpage.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Button.PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) to change the page which the button posts to, and then on the target page, use Page.PreviousPage to get a reference to the source page (and therefore its controls).

By default you can use `Page.PreviousPage.FindControl(...)` to find a control on the source page by ID, then cast it to a checkbox and retrieve its values. You can also specify the type of the previous page with a `<%@ PreviousPageType %>` directive, and then access the previous page's public properties.

See [Cross-Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) for details.